# Проблема с русской кодировкой Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, кодировка

Здравствуйте!

VisualStudio 2012, Service Pack 1. Данный код отображает и считывает русские буквы верно, а выводит не верно :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    printf("Введите какой-нибудь символ. \n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    printf("Код символа %c равен %d \n", ch, ch);


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Если заменить `setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");` на `setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.CP1251");` то эффект ровно обратный.

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Спасибо.

Comment: Ребят, если есть предложения, как устранить данную проблему - пишите!  
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите вот этот [пост](http://it-negr.blogspot.ru/2012/03/c.html). Я думаю, что он будет полезен, хотя, если вы указали в метках язык С, то не факт. Но в любом случае - присмотритесь.

**UPD:**
А вообще можно попробовать сделать так, предварительно подключив хедер Windows.h:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
char ch;
int origCP = GetConsoleCP();

printf("Введите какой-нибудь символ. \n");
SetConsoleCP(1251);
scanf("%s", &ch);
SetConsoleCP(origCP);
printf("Код символа %c равен %d \n", ch, ch);
```

Смысл в том, что нужно менять кодировку локали на ввод и вывод.

Comment: Ну почему же. В scanf/printf можно задать работу с wide char -- форматы %lc (см. описания printf/scanf)

Comment: Хм, спасибо. Такой метод не подходит.